# Saving related objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having some trouble saving related objects with Django Rest Framework. Here are my models

```
# models.py
class PowerStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class VirtualMachine(models.Model):
    power_status = models.ForeignKey(PowerStatus, verbose_name='Power status')
```

My serializers look like this:

```
# serializers.py
class PowerStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = PowerStatus

class VMSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    power_status = PowerStatusSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = VirtualMachine

    def create(self, validated_data):
        power_status_data = validated_data.pop('power_status')
        vm = VirtualMachine.objects.create(**validated_data)
        PowerStatus.objects.create(vm=vm, **power_status_data)

        return vm
```

Error that I'm getting is: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'power_status_id' cannot be null")`

I was following http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects but am doing something wrong.

:EDIT:

After dealing with `Column cannot be null`, another problem arose;

`ValueError: Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('status', 'Running')])": "VirtualMachine.power_status" must be a "PowerStatus" instance.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VirtualMachine model pass null=True to power_status field.

```
class VirtualMachine(models.Model):
    power_status = models.ForeignKey(PowerStatus, verbose_name='Power status', null=True)
```

Comment: Damn, I was looking at this problem from a different angle. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, had to 'unanswer' it because it only answers a part of the problem. I've edited the question.